# Traveling salesman "with tunnels"

Tags: graph-theory

Like everybody on this website it seems, I have a traveling salesman problem. But the traveler wants to visit tunnels, so his exit points are not the entry points, he has to visit all of them, and his travel distance between tunnels has to be minimized. The tunnels are one way, he doesn't get to choose the travel direction.

Is there an academical name for this variant? some google keywords?

Comment: Can you state your problem in precise mathematical language?

Comment: It sounds like asymmetric TSP, but I don't see why tunnels are inherently one-way, so perhaps I'm missing something else you're trying to convey from the use of "tunnels".

Comment: Salomo> not really, if I could I wouldn't be here.

Comment: Hayden > one way worm holes in 2d space? Would that be a better image? it's for an industrial process that can't be done backwards, and I want to minimize the distance spent going from one exit site to the next entry site. I can re-order the sites, but not change the entry/exit point of each site.

Comment: currently I'm simply ordering the entry sites by the Morton distance, because it was simple and somewhat relevant.

Comment: Hayden> I think I can frame it as an asymmetric TSP, thanks. By measuring the distance between two sites as the distance between the exit of the first one to the entry of the other, I get an asymmetric relationship.

Answer (score 2):

The term is "minimum weight Hamiltonian path", although you'll want the directed version.

There is a vertex for each entry point, and the weight of an edge from one of those vertices to another or those vertices is the travel distance from the exit point of the one's tunnel to the entry point of the other's tunnel. $\:$ If there is a specific starting point, then unless [the starting point is one of the entry points and the traveler must start by going through that tunnel], there will also be a vertex for the starting point and the weight of an edge from that to another vertex will be the travel distance between the starting point and the entry point of the other vertex's tunnel.

[This paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.2415.pdf) may be relevant, even though it appears to focus on small $k$, rather than $\: k = n \;$.